# Combobox of toolstrip doesn't have selected value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I try to put a `Combobox` in my `toolstrip` menu .i put it but it doesn't have `selectedvalue`!!!why ?

[image]

But when i put a standard `combobox` it has .

[image]

Comment: No one stops you from creating your own toolstrip on the form(docked down custom control). Built-in toolstrip lacks a lot of features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See MSDN Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> ToolStripComboBox is the ComboBox optimized for hosting in a ToolStrip. A subset of the hosted control's properties and events are exposed at the ToolStripComboBox level, but the underlying ComboBox control is fully accessible through the [ComboBox property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Update**:

Get ComboBox control using `toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox` property.

Code Example:

```
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = new object[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2;
string selValue = toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(); 

// selValue gets "Three"
```

Comment: Thanks so i have to add a combobox to my toolstript menu !!!what should i do ?!!!